# Will a iOS app using Reactive Cocoa in MVVM model consuming much more power than usual app in MVC model?

Tags: ios, mvvm, battery, reactive-cocoa

Will a iOS app using Reactive Cocoa framework in MVVM model consuming much more power than usual app in MVC model?

Because there are many notifications in a app using Reactive Cocoa framework, using KVO, I'm afraid the app will consume too much battery power.

Didn't find answer on google, Anyone have experience about this?

Answer (score 0):

It depends a lot of what you are trying to do, I guess most of the time you are ok with ReactiveCocoa. For example [this](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/octify-notifications-for-github/id913756187?mt=8) app was fully built using ReactiveCocoa and it works perfectly, but again it really depends on what you are trying to achieve. Maybe edit your question an add further detail.

PS: I am afraid your Question is going to get close, and you will get a lot of "opinions" and not straight facts.